# 'if' is not working inside for loop in Django

Tags: python, django-views

```
def get(self, request, course_id, video):
    details = self.get_object(course_id)
    print('video', video)
    response = {}
    if details:
        course_details = CourseSectionDetails.objects.filter(course=course_id).order_by('sort_order')
        course_data = CourseSectionDetailsSerializer(course_details, many=True)

        for section_item in course_data.data:
            section_details = CourseSectionModule.objects.filter(section_id=section_item['section_id'])
            section_data = CourseSectionModuleSerializer(section_details, many=True)
            for module_item in section_data.data:
                module_details = CourseModuleVideos.objects.filter(module_id=module_item['module_id'])
                module_data = CourseModuleVideosSerializer(module_details, many=True)

                for video_item in module_data.data:
                    print(video_item['video_id'])
                    print(video)
                    if video == video_item['video_id']:

                        print('yes')


        return self.jp_response(s_code='HTTP_200_OK', data=response)
```

'If' condition is not working properly, the URL contains the video id. video & video_item['video_id'] have equal values even though the if true state does not work, I don't know how to solve this.Give me any suggestions to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,but it not working and the actual problem is here "if video == video_item['video_id']:"

Comment: I see then try `int(video) == video_item['video_id']`

Comment: Maybe you can typecast both ```video``` and ```video_item['video_id']``` to ```int``` as this ```int(video) == int(video_item['video_id'])```

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is something connected with types which - when you print - only looks like that those values are equal.

Inside this inner loop please make following changes:

```py
for video_item in module_data.data:
    print(video_item['video_id'], type(video_item['video_id']))
    print(video, type(video_item['video_id']))
    if video == video_item['video_id']:
        print('yes')
```

and show us output.

If `video` and `video_item['video_id']` are "custom" objects (not some python objects) then you should check theirs `__eq__` methods to see what for them means "to be equal to the other object of their type"

Answer (score 0):

```
            for video_item in module_data.data:
                print(video_item['video_id'], type(video_item['video_id']))
                print(video_id, type(video_id))
                if video_id == str(video_item['video_id']):
                    print('yes')
```

The answer was obtained using this method.Thank you all for the support and new information